# is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Hey everyone I'm new to VueJs and the template is pure typescript, trying to figure out a way to make a checkbox responsive with a function in a script tag to when onClick, when the checkbox has checked an error of "myFunction is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onClick" appears.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const checkBox = document.getElementById('myCheck') as HTMLInputElement | null

  if (checkBox?.checked) {
    console.log('it exist')
  } else {
    console.log("it dosen't")
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very rare with Vue that you need to directly access the DOM such as `document.getElementById`

I suggest reading the docs on [form input bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html)